# Prevent Facebook Share from showing any image

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a Share button on my page. However, I do NOT want Facebook to display any of the images from the page when the page is shared.

I have tried a blank og:image

```
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

Then Facebook just picks one of the images on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was detecting the Facebook user-agent server-side and then responding with a different webpage, one without any images.